# Windows how to implement start-up?

Tags: windows, boot

If we set an item in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`. Then the item will start-up with the system. Such as this is my current environment:
[image]

Look at that **Free Download Manager**, it provides two arguments for Windows OS:

> "C:\Program Files\Softdeluxe\Free Download Manager\fdm.exe" --hidden

But I want to know which program on the system these two parameters are provided for? I mean when my computer is launch, What commands are running on my system? In my imagination, a command running maybe like:

```
program.exe "C:\Program Files\Softdeluxe\Free Download Manager\fdm.exe" --hidden
```

But I know know what is `program.exe`. If I know it, then I can manually simulate the automatic operation of the system.

Comment: Are you asking how to get a list of everything running on Windows along with the associated command line arguments used to start each of them?

Comment: @Richard Sorry for my English, I have a program with a start-up function written by me. Now I have to reboot PC to debug its start-up function. So I want to know how the OS make the program start-up, then I can simulate this automatic  behavior. That is why I ask this question.

Comment: Then you should ask about the problem you're trying to fix - not about implementation of your idea for debugging that problem. [Your assumptions are incorrect](https://superuser.com/a/1624369/194694) and we're wasting time on something than won't work, while we could be solving your actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking "how does Windows know how to run exe files?"

The answer is found elsewhere in the Registry, but it's not really going to make you happy because handling .exe files is a default capability of the OS. The correct registry keys need to be there, yes, and there are viruses that reset this information and break the system's pretty horribly, but at its root every OS needs to be able to run programs written for it, and so this feature is baked-in to each OS. Not every OS uses .exe files, those are just the most common executable format used in Windows.

If you look at the defined handler EXEFILE in the Registry HKCR hive, you'll find the Data for the Open key is `"%1" %*` which basically means "it runs itself and allows any of its own arguments".

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor English. It seems you don't seem to understand what I'm asking..

Comment: It's possible, but I thought it clear enough after re-reading the question several times. If you believe you've been misunderstood it falls to you to use the EDIT button to correct your question.

Comment: Can I manually simulate the start-up operation of this system? Because a start-up program written by me has a bug, I don't want to reboot my computer to test the function of start-up.

Comment: I'm sorry, you need to ask the question you actually have. Trying to over think things and ask a question that MIGHT point you toward a solution for your actual question doesn't help you or us at all. Please ask the question you actually have. Also, you test a program running at start up by running the program. They behave the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The component of Windows that processes the `Run` registry key is not available
for invocation by the user. The boot environment is also not possible
to simulate after the boot has completed.

However, if the command on the `Run` key is correct, it should run exactly the
same during the boot.

After you have tested it by running in the booted environment,
the only way to test its working during the boot, is to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a wrong assumption. Windows doesn't execute this:

```
program.exe "C:\Program Files\Softdeluxe\Free Download Manager\fdm.exe" --hidden
```

where `program.exe` would be the program executed and `"C:\Program Files\Softdeluxe\Free Download Manager\fdm.exe"` and `--hidden` are two arguments.

Windows executes this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Softdeluxe\Free Download Manager\fdm.exe" --hidden
```

where `"C:\Program Files\Softdeluxe\Free Download Manager\fdm.exe"` is the program executed and `--hidden` is its single argument.

No need to wrap this in an extra program.